# Deprecation Warning for graphql-tools@9.0.0 in NestJS GraphQLModule Configuration

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo

I'm encountering a deprecation warning related to the graphql-tools package in my NestJS application. The warning suggests migrating from graphql-tools@9.0.0 to scoped packages like @graphql-tools/schema. However, I'm having trouble understanding the specific steps for migration.

Here is the relevant part of my NestJS GraphQLModule configuration:

```
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';
import { formattedGraphqlError } from './util';

GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), './schema.gql'),
  sortSchema: true,
  playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  formatError: formattedGraphqlError,
}),
```

As of now, graphql-tools@9.0.0 is only listed in my package.json file and doesn't appear in any import statements. I would like guidance on how to migrate from graphql-tools@9.0.0 to the recommended @graphql-tools/schema package.

Any assistance or clarification on the migration steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found all the documentation I needed at https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/migration-guide.